# Why does the Guava Resources class not have String versions of the methods?

Tags: java, guava

The construct `Resources.toString(Resources.getResource("foo"), Charsets.UTF_8)` feels a little cumbersome.  Why the insistence on conversion to URL's first?  Since the `getResource()` method doesn't throw an exception, why not have parallel `String` methods as well?

Comment: Unless someone involved in the library answers or is quoted, it's all speculation--not sure it's a good fit for SO. I'll guess because URLs are Universal and more generic than strings.

Comment: Personally I'd expect a String overload to accept a `URL` as a string, not a resource name, as I'm much more used to working with URLs (mainly because Jetty's `ClassLoader`'s resource handling's brain is full of f..ail).   Perhaps they wanted to avoid the ambiguity?

Comment: @DaveNewton, most of the Guava team (including yours truly) _does_ keep an eye on the guava tag on StackOverflow, and frequently answers questions like these.  

I don't know the answer to this particular question, so I can't answer, but I think it's perfectly fine to ask this sort of question here, and hope for a Guava team member to respond.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Cool. But it should be on programmers.stackexchange, IMO.

Comment: @LouisWasserman perfectly fine from the Guava view point, but not from the SO viewpoint. I think this is a question that should be asked on a guava mailing list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this all comes down to orthogonality and composability. The API clearly separates *getting* the `URL` of a resource from *doing* something with that resource. This is important because there are a number of ways that you can get the `URL` of a resource. `Resources.getResource("foo")` is one, but it just won't work in some situations. If you need to ensure that a specific `ClassLoader` is used (because Guava may be loaded by a different `ClassLoader` than your application files), you need an alternative way of getting the `URL` such as `Resources.getResource("foo", SomeApplicationClass.class)`.

If `Resources` were to provide overloads of its methods to handle all those cases, the number of methods in the class would triple. That *might* seem acceptable in this particular case, but if similar "shortcuts" were added throughout the library, the number of methods would balloon up very quickly. The library would become much more difficult to digest because you'd have to dig through a sea of methods that do almost the same thing to find what you want. For that reason, Guava favors powerful methods that do one thing and which combine well with other methods. Combining `Resources.toString` with `Resources.getResource` is an example of this.

Of course, that doesn't mean that Guava *never* provides such shortcuts... it just only does so when the addition really seems worth it. For example, most of the methods in the `Files` class *could* be removed since you can just combine `Files.newInputStreamSupplier`, `Files.newWriterSupplier`, etc. with the methods in the `ByteStreams` and `CharStreams` classes to accomplish the same things. Given how common operations on `File`s are, though, the shortcuts were deemed worth it. (Note that overloads that take a `String` filename were *not* added, though.)

Comment: That'd be more compelling if Resources.getResource() threw an exception or something.  I virtually never play around with classloaders in my code, so to me it just feels like an additional hoop to jump through.  Thanks for the answer though.